# fetch a string from a string at different indexes in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, substring

I am having html page .I want to fetch image name from different indexes traversing through entire page.My HTML page is:

```
<html manifest="everything-offline.manifest">
<head>
  <title>Column Test</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/contents.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Pugpig Gazette</h1>

  <section class="topstories">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="article-a1.html">
        <article>
          <h2>Lorizzle ipsizzle dolizzle</h2>
          <figure><img src="img/a1.jpg" /></figure>
        </article>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="article-b1.html">
        <article>
          <h2>Cras accumsizzle</h2>
          <figure><img src="img/b1.jpg" /></figure>
        </article>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="article-c1.html">
        <article>
          <h2>Sizzle go to hizzle</h2>
          <figure><img src="img/c1.jpg" /></figure>
        </article>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="article-d1.html">
        <article>
          <h2>Lorizzle ipsizzle dolizzle</h2>
          <figure><img src="img/d1.jpg" /></figure>
        </article>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="article-d2.html">
        <article>
          <h2>Cras accumsizzle</h2>
          <figure><img src="img/d2.jpg" /></figure>
        </article>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="article-e1.html">
        <article>
          <h2>Sizzle go to hizzle</h2>
          <figure><img src="img/e1.jpg" /></figure>
        </article>
      </a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section class="sections">
    <ul>
      <li class="section-a"><a href="section-index-a.html">News</a></li>
      <li class="section-b"><a href="section-index-b.html">Sport</a></li>
      <li class="section-c"><a href="section-index-c.html">Business</a></li>
      <li class="section-d"><a href="section-index-d.html">Entertainment</a></li>
      <li class="section-e"><a href="section-index-e.html">Finance</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I want to fetch image names as a1.jpg,d1.jpg, e1.jpg etc...
Please guide me how to fetch.Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial on Ray Wenderlich's website to parse HTMLs. Here's the link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios. This should help you understand parsing and also retrieve the image names.

Answer (score 0):

here is the link

http://kelp.phate.org/2012/04/parsing-html-in-ios-app.html

you will find one demo code here.

it may help you.

Happy Coding!!!!!!